# Extract lines with specific dates and execute a command on each of them

Tags: shell, command-line

I'm using a [Google Drive command-line script](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) that can return a list of files such as:

```
Id                             Title                       Size     Created
0Bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   backup-2014-12-26.tar.bz2   569 MB   2014-12-26 18:23:32
```

I want to purge files older than 15 days.

**How can I execute the following command:**

```
drive delete --id 0Bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**with the `Id` of all the lines that have a `Created` date older than 15 days?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apparently use the Google api to list and sort the files to your needs specifically *(from `drive --help`)*:

```
list:
    -m, --max      Max results
    -q, --query    Query (see https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters)
```

...and from the link...

- Search for files modified after June 4th 2012

```
    modifiedDate > '2012-06-04T12:00:00'    // default time zone is UTC
    modifiedDate > '2012-06-04T12:00:00-08:00'
```

*Note that the example searches for files **newer** than a certain date...*

So this isn't very difficult at all, though, for whatever reason, `drive` seems capable of handling only a single argument per invocation:

```
mdate_list() { drive list -nq \
    "modifiedDate $1 '$(date -ud"$2" '+%FT%T')' and \
     mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
}  
rmdrv() for dfile do drive delete -i "$dfile" || return; done

set -f; unset IFS            #no split data mangling, please
while   set -- $(mdate_list \< '15 days ago'|cut -d\  -f1)  
        [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
do      rmdrv "$@" || ! break
done
```

I only instituted the `while` loop at all in case you have too many drive files to handle in a single listing - most of the time you will easily do without it, but if there are a great many, this will keep populating the list until there are no more.

The rest just happens as a result of the data you feed it. Note that I specifically excluded folders here, but you will probably want to look at the link mentioned as well if there is anything else you might want to tweak.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer to the question I should have asked in the first place :)

Comment: @Benjamin - thanks for pointing out `drive` to me - kinda peeved about that one file arg per invoke though...

Comment: @Benjamin - made the `mdate...()` fn take a couple parameters, and... well... it might actually work now. That's the sloppiest accept I've ever got. Anyway, thanks again, and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the list of the files are in a file named `x.txt`, a bash script as follows could do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS="\n"
for i in $(cat x.txt)
do
    fid=$(echo $i | awk '{print $1}') # extract the file id
    d=$(echo $i | awk '{print $5}') # extract the date filed
    d2=$(date -d "$d" +%s)  # convert it to epoch sec

    now=$(date +%s) # current time in epoch sec
    diff=$(( (now - d2) / 86400 )) # find diff and convert it to days
    echo "The file $fid is $diff days old"
    if (( $diff > 15 )) #if the diff is greater than 15 
    then
      #delete file
      drive delete --id $fid
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I just had to replace `\n` with an actual newline between the quotes, or it would cut a line in the middle for an obscure reason!

Comment: I also noticed that `[[ $diff > 15]]` actually compares the numbers as strings (so `'2'` > `'15'`), I needed to replace this with `(( $diff > 15 ))`. See [comparing numbers in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18668556/759866).

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks, I made an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple with `awk`

```
drive list |\
awk 'BEGIN{ "date +%s -d -15\\ days" | getline n }
        $6{ m=$5"\\ "$6
            ("date +%s -d "m) | getline t
            if(t < n) system("drive delete -id "$1) }'
```

Comment: I get this output: `awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence '\ ' treated as plain ' '
date: extra operand ‘days’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
date: extra operand ‘18:23:32’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
date: extra operand ‘17:49:11’
Try 'date --help' for more information.`

Comment: @Benjamin Try with double "\" or without it at all.